# Springfox not generating Swagger docs correctly for same operation-endpoint, different query parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox

Springfox doesn't generate correctly the swagger doc for a simple case like this one:

`GET /api/departments - Gets all department`

`GET /api/departments?name=IT - Gets a department with name passed as query parameter`

This is the Spring Controller:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Gets all departments", notes = "", tags = {"departments"})
@RequestMapping(value="/departments", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Department> getAllDepartments(){
       ...
}

@ApiOperation(value = "Gets a department by name", notes = "", tags = {"departments"})
@RequestMapping(value="/departments", params="name", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Department getDepartmentByName(@RequestParam String name){
    ...
}
```

The generated swagger file only contains the GET /api/departments entry, not a trace of the one with the query filter.

Any workaround?

Swagger Config:

```
@Bean
public Docket departmentsV1Api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*"))                
        .build()
        .apiInfo(new ApiInfo("Departments Rest API","","v1","","","",""))
        .pathMapping("/api")
        .securitySchemes(newArrayList(apiKey()))
        .securityContexts(newArrayList(securityContext()))
        .groupName("departmentsV1");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This use case isn't supported by the spec. However you could use the `enableUrlTemplating(true)` method in your `docket` to enable rfc6570 support.

There is also an experimental library ([springfox-swagger-ui-rfc6570](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui-rfc6570)) that can be used as a drop-in replacement for the standard `springfox-swagger-ui`.

***Note:*** Keep in mind this is in incubation and can change when support is added in the spec.